# Converting fields to properties with non-trivial set method to react to changes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mono, reflection.emit

Consider I have a data structure:

```
class Data
{
    [Property]
    public int i = 3;

    [Property]
    public UserDefined test = new UserDefined { prop = something; };
}
```

I'm looking for a way to convert this in runtime to:

```
class Data : PropertyContainer
{
    private int _i = 3;
    public int i
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _i; 
        }

        set 
        {
            _i = value;
            NotifyChange("i"); // member of PropertyContainer base class
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible at all? Can I did it with `Reflection.Emit`? If not what's the closest thing I could archive? My requirements are performance, performance and convenience to frequently modify such data structures and not bother with implementation details. I need regularly (15Hz) check for changes and send delta from server to client.

I already tried to build a schema by reflection and keep a last synced state. Each tick I compared the last state with actual data by traversing data structure, detecting changed parts and building delta. It's an ideal approach from usage convenience but even optimized to cache all reflection calls except FieldType.GetValue/SetValue still provides poor performance because data structure is too large for this frequency. Half the time I spend in GetValue and the rest traversing a hierarchical structure. The problem is I'm bound to structure size and need to traverse all fields each time despite changes happen not so often.

Comment: Well if performance is important, converting it at runtime is not a good plan. An appropriate approach is likely to do something like what PostSharp does. Hook into the compiler and build IL at compile time.

Comment: Do you want to just add INotifyPropertyChanged without writing much code for it? In that case you could use Fody extension https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: unfortunately I use Mono thru Unity3D and cannot modify compilation

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh: see my comment above please

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: performance is important, but not just abstract performance. Using different approach to react to changes instead of to detect them proactively as in the described approach would provide (I hope so!) sufficient performance.

Comment: @Andy T, did you look at [this articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer)? It's about .net, not mono. But may be there's something similar for mono...